# cannot launch apps

Tags: 20.04, gnome

`$ nautilus`

Error message:

```
Usage: nautilus [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]
nautilus: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type youtube-dl --help to see a list of all options.
```

When I try to open any application that was installed via apt it fails with this message.
If I click the icon I just get spinning wheels and then it fails.
I purged youtube-dl, but it did not fix it.
Apps installed with snap work just fine.

When I look in /usr/share/applications I see files such as:
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
...but I'm not sure how to run it if I can't use files to go and double click.

`apt-cache policy nautilus` gives the following output:

```
  Installed: 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.36.3-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.36.1.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

This was solved with:

```
sudo rm $(which nautilus)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

...and I had to repeat for each of the applications that would not launch `file-roller`, `vlc`, `gedit`.

Comment: Try to reinstall the Nautilus package by `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus` then run it using `nautilus` command from the terminal. If it fails - add output of `apt-cache policy nautilus` and `ldd $(which nautilus)` to the question.

Comment: Thanks N0rbert I ran the reinstall - it reinstalled same version, no errors. `nautilus` gives the same original error.

Comment: I updated the original question with ```apt-cache policy nautilus``` and ```ldd $(which nautilus)``` gives the error ```not a dynamic executable```

Comment: "not a dynamic executable" is weird. Please then show output of `which nautilus`

Answer (score 1):

This is weird. It looks like your `nautilus` is launching `youtube-dl`, which is reporting an error often seen (web search for *youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL*).

So you would need to report the output of a few diagnostic commands.

```
$ strace nautilus > ~/strace_nautilus.txt 2>&1
$ strace youtube-dl > ~/strace_youtube-dl.txt 2>&1
```

Since the output (stdout/stderr) is possibly long, these commands dump it to file. You would post these files in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).
Also

```
$ type nautilus
$ which nautilus
$ ldd $(which nautilus)
$ mkdir -p ~/temp/askubuntu
$ cd ~/temp/askubuntu
$ nautilus "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-dYNttdgl0"
$ youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-dYNttdgl0"
$ ls -al $(which nautilus)
$ uname -a
```

(see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367266/cannot-launch-apps#comment2348332_1367266)).

**Notes**:

1. Avoid "narrating" what you obtained; copy+paste the output.
2. Include from copy+paste also the exact command you entered.)
3. If command `ls ...` shows a soft link, also post the output of `ls <target of the soft link>`, and keep doing this if you further get soft links, until you get an actual file as the target.

**Related**:

1. https://www.tecmint.com/strace-commands-for-troubleshooting-and-debugging-linux/

Comment: Thanks sancho. I pasted the strace in here: [strace_nautilus1] (https://pastebin.com/Sw5t9J3n) || [strace_nautilus2] (https://pastebin.com/SjvahkvE) || [strace_youtube_dl] (https://pastebin.com/CNrqQL0B) || [terminal] (https://pastebin.com/hQum7YLp) -- I was able to download the vivaldi using youtube-dl and play it, but ffmpeg caused it to fail in nautilus.

Comment: ```$ type nautilus```
```nautilus is hashed (/usr/local/bin/nautilus)
```
```$ which nautilus```
```/usr/local/bin/nautilus
```
```$ ldd $(which nautilus)```
```not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: @user1443742 - 
Please make for an easier reading of those who try to help:
1) Add your information, suitably formatted, in the question, not in comments.
2) Use pastebin only for extended output, suitably organized into links. For commands with short output, post directly in the question.
3) Please include also the commands I have now added.

Answer (score 0):

Your nautilus installation is a kind of broken. On normally installed system the output of `ldd $(which nautilus)` contains 105 lines of relevant *so*-libraries.

So you have to determine the output of `which nautilus` and then reinstall its packages. If output differs from `/usr/bin/nautilus` then you have to remove this wrong executable by `sudo rm $(which nautilus)` and then reinstall is using command below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```